# pandas str.replace - keep current value if regex fails to avoid NaN in converting string to numbers

Tags: python, regex, pandas, replace

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html

I have a column of values formatted as Strings, some includes a comma, as such:

```
0     20,7
1       22
2       21
3       20
4     24,4
5     23,8
6     23,6
7     21,6
8     24,3
9     23,3
10    24,2

....

17053      16
17054      16
17055      15
17056      15
17057      19
17058      17
17059      18
17060      19
17061      20
17062      21
17063      20
```

I want to convert them as float.

Now, I cannot directly apply astype or to_numeric method, otherwise strings as "20,7" won't be interpreted.

The strange thing is that if apply `.str.replace(',', '.')` to strings that DOES NOT contain the pattern, the regex fails, and return to NaN. I would have expected a replacement if pattern is found, else return the value as it is.

I triead also `.str.replace(',', '.', regex = False)` with no success.

Example:

For values like "20,7" the replacement dot to comma works fine, and I can then convert to number, getting a float 20.7.

But I also have these values:

```
test['TMEDIA °C'][-10:]

17054    16
17055    15
17056    15
17057    19
17058    17
17059    18
17060    19
17061    20
17062    21
17063    20
```

and apply str.replace I get this:

```
test['TMEDIA °C'][-10:].str.replace(',', '.')

17054   NaN
17055   NaN
17056   NaN
17057   NaN
17058   NaN
17059   NaN
17060   NaN
17061   NaN
17062   NaN
17063   NaN
```

and cannot apply astype to the whole column, instead I would like to get this:

```
test['TMEDIA °C'][-10:].astype(float)
17054    16.0
17055    15.0
17056    15.0
17057    19.0
17058    17.0
17059    18.0
17060    19.0
17061    20.0
17062    21.0
17063    20.0
```

Is it a bug of str.replace() or how can I keep the current value if regex fails ?

Comment: No it will fail anyway, cannot convert string to float. A solution to my problem is `test['TMEDIA °C'].apply(lambda x : str(x).replace(',','.')).astype(float) ` but I am waiting to post it as an answer, for I d like a better understanding if the srt.replace method of pandas can also let the result as it is found.

Comment: 1) `str.replace(',', '.')` works fine on my system (pandas 0.25). 2) you maybe able to solve your problem with `pd.read_csv(thousands=',')`.

Comment: @QuangHoang by "works fine" you mean that values not containing a comma, are preserved  (you don't get NaN)?

Comment: That is exactly what I meant. See the [live code](https://ideone.com/k3tRJF).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those with `NaN` after `replace` having dtype `int`, so `replace` returns NaN. Try force converting whole column to `str` before calling `str.replace`

```
test['TMEDIA °C'].astype(str).str.replace(',', '.')
```

Answer (score 3):

Most likely you have a column with mixed data types, something like this:

```
fails = pd.DataFrame([['1,2'], [3]], columns=['a'])
print(fails['a'].str.replace(',', '.'))  # results in NaN
```

How the column ended up like this, is another question. If you had instead:

```
works = pd.DataFrame([['1,2'], ['3']], columns=['a'])
```

then it works.

The mixed data types can for example occur if you concatenate two data frames:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['1,2']], columns=['a'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[3]], columns=['a'])
fails = pd.concat([df1, df2])
```

If `df2` was generated by `read_csv` and it had no `","` values then it is automatically parsed into numbers instead of strings for example.

You can avoid the NaN issue either by using `.str.replace` on the data frame that contains the comma values, here `df1`, *before* concatenating with the other data frame, or by ensuring that the other data frame's column (here `d2['a']`) has `dtype=str` as well (e.g. via `read_csv(..., dtype=str)`).

Comment: indeed I concatenated. You were right, mixed data types. I was disoriented for I saw a `dtype` `Òbject` for all the column, ad though all of values were instances of same type, instead it was mixed of integer and commas. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: @user305883 Then the best way to solve this issue is either to sanitize the data frame with `,` values (here `df1`) before concatenating (i.e. with `.str.replace`), or specify `dtype=str` for `read_csv` for the one without `,` (`df2`) or convert to `str` before concatenating (priority in that order I'd say). If it solved your problem please consider accepting one of the answers so the question is marked as resolved.

Comment: you are right. About "please consider accepting one of the answers so the question is marked as resolved". I found your answer clear for explaining a good practice how to handle data-santization; above answer by Andy is short effective solution explaining why I was meeting NaN.

I found and upvoted both as useful, I think both are correct.
I am puzzled, according to StackOverflow should I mark as correct the answer offering a broader understanding, the one more pin-point to the question or the one I read it first ..? 
I comment here for don't want to offend nor put off none of you

Comment: @user305883 You should accept the answer that you used for solving your problem. [Andy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58512160/3767239) suggests that you cure the issue by converting the column to `str` before performing the replace, while I suggest to avoid the issue by either performing the replace on one data frame before concatenation with the other, or make sure that both data frames have `dtype=str` before the concatenation (e.g. via `read_csv(dtype=str)`). Whichever solution you chose in the end, you should accept.

Comment: Anyway it's your question, so it's really your choice what answer you accept as a solution to your problem. Nobody will feel offended by that, that's how the site works. And mostly we're here to help, not to collect points :-) If you're really having a hard time deciding on one of the answers you could also go with the following: `python -c "import random; print(random.choice(['Andy L.', 'a_guest']))"` Having Python decide on a Python question is probably as fair as it can get ;-)

Comment: Ahah! you're funny, Guest! I much appreciate your spirit.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = pd.Series(['foo', 'fuz', 'some other'])
idx = s[s.str.contains(r'f', regex=True)].index
s.loc[idx] = s.loc[idx].str.replace('f', 'F')
display(s)

0           Foo 
1           Fuz
2    some other
dtype: object
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but include an explanation what the code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are generally of higher quality, and more likely to attract upvotes.